# How to move iPhone contacts to Outlook 2016? (and sync in future)

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have an iPhone which I will shortly be losing. I want to copy the contacts from it to Outlook 2016 on my Windows 10 laptop. My new phone will be either iPhone or Android (not yet decided), and I would like to sync Outlook 2016 with whatever phone I decide to buy in the future.

In the short term, how can I copy the contacts from my current iPhone to Outlook 2016? I've read another thread which suggested creating a Microsoft cloud account, adding it to the iPhone, then syncing, but I'm concerned that the initial sync will wipe all of the contacts from the iPhone (I've had that sort of problem before when moving between devices with iTunes), so want to make sure that the contacts on the iPhone are backed up or copied somewhere before I perform any sort of sync.

Answer (score 0):

### Export and Backup

I guess you can do that with MS cloud account. If you're afraid of wiping out your contacts list with this, try to backup everything with iCloud or any specialized app. Here's one you could try first:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-contacts-backup/id446784593?mt=8

To backup contacts with this app, tap Backup in its interface. Then tap Email, attach generated VCF file to an email and send it to your Gmail.

### Syncing

If you want to sync contacts between iPhone (or your possible future Android phone) with Outlook, then take a look at Akruto:
http://www.akruto.com/sync-iphone-with-outlook/

This software can sync anything from Outlook to smartphone including contact pictures. Works via Wi-Fi router and over the Internet. And another solution is using iCloud to sync everything.